# Kibana npm install error

Tags: node.js

I have tried to install Kibana 4 on Linux (ubuntu) and keep getting an error when I install via `npm install` (`npm --version` shows **1.3.10**).  I checked out the Kibana4 source from github.

It seems that the installer cannot find the latest `spalger/numeral` package, but if I do `npm install numeral` it installs **some** numeral package, but evidently not the right one.  I don't guess I know enough about NPM to make this work, so I'm looking for ideas here.

It outputs a bunch of successful stuff with this in the middle:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/0.4.4
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/spalger/angular-bootstrap/0.12.1
npm ERR! 404 'spalger' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-62-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/mike/code/kibana4
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! code E404
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/spalger/filesaver/1.1.2
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/spalger/leaflet-draw/0.2.3
```

Then, it outputs a bunch more stuff and this at the bottom:

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sinon/1.17.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/spalger/numeral
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/spalger/numeral
npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:687:35)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:675:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-62-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/mike/code/kibana4
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! type non_object_property_load
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mike/code/kibana4/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/code/kibana4$
```

I have tried to just install the numeral package:

`npm install @spalger/numeral` and I get an error, too:

```
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/code/kibana4$ npm install @spalger/numeral
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/spalger/numeral
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/spalger/numeral
npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:687:35)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:675:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-62-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "@spalger/numeral"
npm ERR! cwd /home/mike/code/kibana4
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! type non_object_property_load
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mike/code/kibana4/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/code/kibana4$
```

Comment: As I said, I checked out Kibana 4 from github: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/tree/4.x

Comment: And how it relates to npm and node?

Comment: In the install documentation, you execute `npm install` after you check the project out.  Then, the output I posted is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  I had to update Node, because it did not work with the older version.

Ubuntu's package manger did not want to upgrade (i.e. apt-get didn't give me a newer version) so I removed the symlinks to `nodejs` and `node` from `/usr/local/bin`, installed node from the website and created symlinks to the newly installed version.

Now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Kibana 4 requirements:

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "0.12.9",
    "npm": "2.14.3"
  }
```

**Just update your node and/or npm**

Or try kibana 3.x

Comment: This should be a comment.  I have listed all my commands that I have run.  I also just updated after trying to install only that package, and it does not work.